# Expected [false] to be false protractor e2e test failure

Tags: javascript, jasmine, protractor

I am getting following error when executing my script, not sure what I am doing wrong.

My TestScript.js :

```
expect(Panel.CommentSave.isEnabled()).toBe(false);

Panel.CommentTxt.sendKeys('1234');
expect(Panel.CommentSave.isEnabled()).toBe(true);
```

Result:

```
Expected [false] to be false

Expected [true] to be true
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong my test is failing.

Will appreciate any help on this, thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the selector for "CommentSave"? is it an element.all?

Comment: you are comparing array of elements with single Boolean value. Try to get the particular element and do assert.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To elaborate what @Andres D asked about, it looks like the `Panel.CommentSave` page object field is [`ElementArrayFinder` - the result of `element.all()` call](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder).

Instead, either use `element()` instead of `element.all()` to define the page object field, or use [`first()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.first):

```
expect(Panel.CommentSave.first().isEnabled()).toBe(false);

Panel.CommentTxt.sendKeys('1234');
expect(Panel.CommentSave.first().isEnabled()).toBe(true);
```

Comment: thank you @alecxe  this solved the problem... I was using element.all and changed it to element and it worked. thanks a lot